# file_get_contents HTTP request failed error

Tags: php, curl

So I have GetMessages.php, this script gets data out of an database(MongoDB). Then it makes a cURL POST to MyMessagesMDB.php. This is the code:

```
<?php
$FirstName = '';
$LastName = '';
$Email = '';
$Subject = '';
$Message = '';

GetFromDB();

echo $FirstName." ".$LastName;
echo "<br>";
echo $Email;
echo "<br>";
echo $Subject;
echo "<br>";
echo $Message;
echo "<br>";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.0.163/MyMessagesMDB.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "FirstName=$FirstName&LastName=$LastName&Email=$Email&Subject=$Subject&TextMessage=$Message");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

function GetFromDB(){
    $client = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb+srv://####:####@####.tldyu.mongodb.net/Data');
    $filter = [];
    $options = [];
    $query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
    $cursor = $client->executeQuery('ContactMessages.ContactForm', $query);

    foreach($cursor as $document){
        $document = json_decode(json_encode($document),true);

        global $FirstName, $LastName, $Email, $Subject, $Message;
        $FirstName = $document['FirstName'];
        $LastName = $document['LastName'];
        $Email = $document['Email'];
        $Subject = $document['Subject'];
        $Message = $document['Message'];
    }
}
?>
```

MyMessagesMDB.php is the script to get called first. It calls GetMessages.php and should then receive the information it has posted. Here is the code:

```
<?php
$FirstLoop = true;
if($FirstLoop == true){
    file_get_contents('http://192.168.0.102/test/GetMessages.php');
    $FirstLoop = false;
}

$FirstName = $_POST["FirstName"] ?? "";
$LastName = $_POST["LastName"] ?? "";
$Email = $_POST["Email"] ?? "";
$Subject = $_POST["Subject"] ?? "";
$Message = $_POST["TextMessage"] ?? "";

echo $FirstName." ".$LastName;
echo "<br>";
echo $Email;
echo "<br>";
echo $Subject;
echo "<br>";
echo $Message;
echo "<br>";
?>
```

But here starts my problem.

If I call MyMessagesMDB.php I get the error:

> PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://192.168.0.102/test/GetMessages.php): Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!.

If I try to load the page manually I get no error and the data out of the database is printed on the screen.

When in MyMessagesMDB.php I comment the following line like this:

> #file_get_contents('http://192.168.0.102/test/GetMessages.php');

I can load the page without any problem or error.

**The Question**

What do I have to do to call GetMessages.php from MyMessagesMDB.php and receive the information out of the database?

Note: I have tried

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, 
CURLOPT_URL,'http://###.##.##.##/mp/get? 
mpsrc=http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/11111.mpg&mpaction=convert 
format=flv');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Your application 
name');
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
```

Comment: In your question can you please rename Script A and B to the name of their files, it's a bit hard to keep track.

Comment: Yup, my fault. I changed it!

Comment: I'm a bit confused, so GetMessages calls MyMessagesMDB which then calls GeMessages again, is this not an infinite loop? What is it you're trying to accomplish? I might be able to give some tips on how to organise your code better

Comment: So MyMessagesMDB.php will be an webpage that will display the content out of the database, this file will be hosted on a server from my school. To get the data out of the database I call GetMessages.php and then post the content to the MyMessagesMDB.php page. I can't connect directly to the database from the schools servers so that's why I need the GetMessages.php file. It acts as a middleman between school and the database.

Comment: Ah yes I think I understand now. So you want MyMessagesMDB to be both the script that you run locally to start getting stuff from the database and also the script that receives the information? Current in your GetMessages script, it will only get the last message if there is more than 1 document in it, is that intended?

Comment: Yes indeed, thats what i want to create! Yeah I know I didn't get so for yet to show all of the items but that's least of my worries, first fixing the big problem will be a big step forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After our comments back and forth, I think your implementation is way more complicated than it needs to be. Instead of `MyMessagesMDB.php` acting as both an initiator of the process and a recipient of data, it only needs to be an initiator.

In this implementation, `mdb.php` acts as the script that would sit with your database, it's whole job is to take everything from the `ContactMessages.ContactForm` query and output it as JSON.

```
<?php

$client = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb+srv://####:####@####.tldyu.mongodb.net/Data');
$filter = [];
$options = [];
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
$cursor = $client->executeQuery('ContactMessages.ContactForm', $query);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($cursor);
```

Then you have `get.php`, which you have on the server at school, which uses `file_get_contents` to get the JSON, and then convert it back to a PHP array, which you can then output however you see fit.

```
<?php

$mdb_url = 'http://192.168.0.102/test/GetMessages.php';
$get = file_get_contents($mdb_url);
$decoded = json_decode($get, true);

foreach ($decoded as $document) {
    echo $document['FirstName'] . '<br>' . 
        $document['LastName'] . '<br>' . 
        $document['Email'] . '<br>' . 
        $document['Subject'] . '<br>' . 
        $document['Message'] . '<br><hr>';
}
```

Comment: It is not echoing anything at the moment, but I'll check it out tomorow and let you know if I can get it to work. Big thanks already!

Comment: You're welcome, it's an interesting problem this one! Let me know how you go :)

Comment: Your solution works, I just altered a few things and now I have a working system, big thankyou! @mulquin

Comment: @MikeAelbrecht you're welcome mate, good luck with it all!